# Scala type annotation without type

Tags: scala

Found [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Filters.scala#L32) odd type annotation:

```
trait Filter extends EssentialFilter {
  self =>
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

It just creates an alias for `this`. Consider this as a possible use case:

```
trait Foo { self => 
  def name: String
  case class Bar(val name)  {
     def showNames = println(
       s"My name: ${this.name}, foo's name: ${self.name}"
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: In addition to this answer, I recommend this helpful blog post - http://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html - which discusses `=> self`.